# SQL Filter rows on groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a sql table with say 100 rows.
the structure is somthing like

```
colectiveNo    colectiveName         p1Number        P1EffectiveFromDate   morecol
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                  name1             somenumber         somedate            NULL
1                  name1             somenumber         somedate            1234
1                  name1             somenumber         somedate            5432
```

we group by , by colectiveNo

i want to use conditon like this:

1. if  row from the group with "morcol" is null and 
   there is row in the same group with morcol with some number
   dont show the row with the null
   show row 2,3
2. ELSE
   if i have only rows with morecol is null show them for that group

.

```
colectiveNo    colectiveName         p1Number        P1EffectiveFromDate   morecol
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                name1           somenumber         somedate            NULL
    1                name1           somenumber         somedate            NULL
    1                name1           somenumber         somedate            NULL
```

show row 1,2,3

i'm getting difficult to do that please help

Comment: so in your given records, what would be the result?

Comment: the 2,3 rows without the NULL colume (1)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it, you said you group on colectiveNo, so I will assume that your second example full of nulls is a different group of colectiveNo

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT   colectiveNo
                ,colectiveName
                ,p1Number
                ,p1EffectiveFromDate
                ,morecol
                ,CASE WHEN MAX(morecol) OVER (PARTITION BY colectiveNo) IS NULL  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS fldIncNulls 
        FROM tbltest
    )data
WHERE (morecol IS NOT NULL OR fldIncNulls = 1)
```